# How to get Paged DataTable from PagedDataSource?

Tags: datatable, pagination, dataset, datasource, datarow

I've a situation here, I'm using **PagedDataSource** to bind pagination to my **Calender (some 3rd party control)**

Here it's working fine. But problem is I need paged data; after assigning it to control. Say for e.g:

```
DataSet ds = DbGetEvents(DayPilotCalendar1.StartDate, DayPilotCalendar1.Days);
var pds = new PagedDataSource
{DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView, AllowPaging = true, CurrentPageIndex = _position, PageSize = 2};
Calender.DataSource=pds;
```

After this I need a Paged DataTable from it.

```
DataTable dt= /* here I need to access Paged DataTable from **paged** */
```

How to do this? Is It possible? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataView dView = (DataView)pagedDataSource.DataSource;
DataTable dTable;
dView.Sort = ordenarPor;
dTable = (DataTable)dView.Table;
pds.DataSource = dTable.DefaultView;
```